# Radcombobox selectedindexchanged not firing on the CodeBehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

i wrote this telerik radComboBox

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel17" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfld_FlgCall" runat="server" />

                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 ">
                                <label for="status" class=" control-label">عیب </label>
                                <div class="">
                                    <%--OnClientKeyPressing="HandleKeyPress"--%>
                                    <telerik:RadComboBox Skin="Bootstrap" ID="drpd_Defect" OnClientKeyPressing="HandleKeyPress" onkeyup="HandleKeyup(this);" OnClientDropDownOpened="peraperToChaneLanguageDefect" OnClientDropDownClosing="peraperToChaneLanguageDefect"
                                        Culture="fa-IR" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" EmptyMessage="انتخاب کنید"
                                        AllowCustomText="True" DropDownAutoWidth="Disabled" Filter="Contains" 
                                        RenderMode="Auto" Width="100%" Height="200px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpd_Defect_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                    </telerik:RadComboBox>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                          
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

But when i use breakPoint in code behind on SelectedIndexChanged , this method didn't called.

Where is my mistake?

I got confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aow my goddddddd
i'm so sorry for Microsoft visual studio
I made some changes in the codebehind and use new feature in Visual Studio ---> Apply Code Change --- on run mode-
but this feature didn't work correctly
when I stop app and rerun the project my breakpoint work